# vlc decoder error while streaming

Tags: linux, centos7, video-streaming

I'm re-streaming rtsp stream with vlc for two cameras. The second camera doesn't have audio and it works fine, for the first one (**which has audio**) stream start fails 9 out of 10 times with error **"`core decoder error: cannot continue streaming due to errors`"**. However if the streams starts, it works fine until restarted. However I get some errors on the cam 1 (when the stream starts correctly):

```
core mux warning: late buffer for mux input (145003)
```

And sometimes (rarely) I get these errors:

mux_ts mux warning: packet with too strange dts (dts=-6272,old=0,pcr=0)

I'm using VLC 2.2.4 on CentOS7 from nux-dextop repo:

```
VLC media player 2.2.4 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.3-37-g888b7e89)
```

It's installed on Virtual machine without desktop and probably **doesn't have any audio support (no virtual audio hardware)**.

vlc start script for the first camera (s):

```
#!/bin/bash

URL="rtsp://192.168.40.201:554/axis-media/media.amp"

#--rtsp-frame-buffer-size=200000 \
sudo -u vlc cvlc -v \
 --loop --http-reconnect --http-continuous -I dummy $URL \
 --logfile=/var/log/bird-cam1.log \
 --sout '#transcode{}'\
':duplicate{dst=std{access=livehttp{seglen=3,delsegs=true,numsegs=5,index=/var/www/html/live/cam1/mystream.m3u8,index-url=http://10.20.30.40/live/cam1/mystream-########.ts},mux=ts{use-key-frames},'\
'dst=/var/www/html/live/cam1/mystream-########.ts},'\
'dst=std{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:8081/video.mp4}}'
```

vlc output

```
VLC media player 2.2.4 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.3-37-g888b7e89)
[0000000000b4f348] core interface error: no suitable interface module
[0000000000a50118] core libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[0000000000b4f348] dbus interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus session daemon: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
[0000000000b4f348] core interface error: no suitable interface module
[0000000000a50118] core libvlc error: interface "dbus,none" initialization failed
[0000000000b4f348] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
MultiFramedRTPSource::doGetNextFrame1(): The total received frame size exceeds the client's buffer size (100000).  75129 bytes of trailing data will be dropped!
[00007fb95c0009b8] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[00007fb960005148] mux_ts mux warning: packet with too strange dts (dts=-6457,old=0,pcr=0)
[00007fb9604d1228] mux_ts mux warning: packet with too strange dts (dts=-6457,old=0,pcr=0)
[00007fb95c0009b8] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[00007fb96051d348] core decoder error: cannot continue streaming due to errors
```

Any ideas why the stream doesn't start every time?
Both cameras stream RTSP. Codec h264 AVC, for the first camera audio is mp4a

**Update:**

Confirmed that the audio is causing the problem. With audio stream stopped vlc works just fine. Audio codec is AAC. It was set to 32kHz sampling/32 kbit/s. Now it's 48kHz sampling/64kbit/s - still the same problem.

**Update:**

I tried different settings in the camera for AAC - 16kHz - same result. Setting audio to G.711 resulted "unsupported coded" error, but stream was still able to start even though audio wasn't working.